# Mern app not rendering react components on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy a mern app to heroku, but when viewing it in the browser using heroku local, it only shows me my data in json, no react components. Everything works in my local environment. I was thinking it might be a problem with my express routes and react routes crashing and the express route being loaded instead of react, but I can't figure it out.

express routes:

```
const router = express.Router();

// Palette Model
const Palette = require("../models/Palette");

// @route   GET api/palettes
// @desc    Get All Palettes
// @access  Public
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Palette.find().then(palettes => res.json(palettes));
});

// @route   POST api/palettes/new
// @desc    Create A Palette
// @access  Public
router.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  const newPalette = new Palette({
    name: req.body.name,
    colors: req.body.colors
  });

  newPalette
    .save()
    .then(palette => res.json(palette))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  console.log(req.body);
});

// @route   GET api/palettes/:id
// @desc    Get A Palette
// @access  Public
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Palette.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(palette => res.json(palette))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nopalettefound: "No Palette found" }));
});

// @route   PUT api/palette/edit/:id
// @desc    Update A Palette
// @access  Public
router.put("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  Palette.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
    .then(palette => res.json({ msg: "Updated successfully" }))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(400).json({ error: "Unable to update the Database" })
    );
});

// @route   DELETE api/palettes/:id
// @desc    Delete A Palette
// @access  Public
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Palette.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(palette => palette.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

react router:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/api/palettes"
  >
    <PaletteList />
  </Route>
  <Route
    path="/api/palettes/new"
  >
    <NewPaletteForm />
  </Route>
  <Route
    path="/api/palettes/edit/:id"
    render={routeProps => <EditPalette {...routeProps} />}
  ></Route>
  <Route
    path="/api/palettes/:id"
    render={routeProps => <Palette {...routeProps} />}
  ></Route>
</Switch>
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I would very much appreciate it!!

Comment: Can you share more about how you’re running it locally? Are you running a separate backend and frontend?

Comment: Yes, I am using concurrently to run the backend and frontend on two different ports